# "Einzahlen auf" im Sinne von "zur Verwirklichung von x beitragen": Wo kommt das her?

Tags: etymology

Aus dem Munde von Leuten aus Management-Etagen höre ich in letzter Zeit öfters den Ausdruck "einzahlen auf", zum Beispiel:

> Unsere Umstellung auf xyz-Methodik wird **einzahlen auf** das Bla-Bla-Blupp-Projekt.

> Mit der Schnelldigitalisierungs-Taskforce **zahlen wir ein auf** das Onlinezugangsgesetz.<sup>1</sup>

> Das ist ein Paket, das **einzahlt auf** die Fragen der Zukunft.<sup>2</sup>

Ich schließe aus dem Kontext, dass etwas gemeint ist wie "beitragen zur Umsetzung von" oder "beitragen zur Lösung von" u.s.w.

Meine Frage: Wo kommt diese eigenartige Phrase her?

**Zusatzgedanken:**

Ich hätte vermutet: So was kommt ja heutzutage meist als hölzerne Direktübertragung aus dem Englischen/Amerikanischen; so wie ja auch Phrasen wie "am Ende des Tages" oder "Sinn machen" einfach Direktübersetzungen von Geschäftsleute-Englisch sind. Einen Nachweis von etwas wie "xyz pays in on s.th." habe ich aber bisher noch nicht entdeckt.

Der Duden kennt die Phrase übrigens so weit ich sehe noch nicht (Datum 23. Feb. 2021). Das wundert mich, denn ich begegne ihr im beruflichen Alltag sehr oft, und durchaus in einem breiten Spektrum von Firmen.

Die Phrase ist insofern auffällig, als sie die etablierte Syntax des Verbs *einzahlen* verbiegt. Wohl kennt man im Deutschen die Wendung "(Geld) einzahlen auf's Sparbuch". Hier ist jedoch stehts als Akteur ein menschliches Subjekt notwendig (*Fritz zahlt 50 Mark aufs Sparbuch ein*). Ein anderes (nicht-menschliches) Subjekt ist hier nicht akzeptabel. In der betriebswirtesprachlichen Verwendung wie oben zitiert hingegen wird nun eben doch ein beliebiges konkretes oder abstraktes Ding subjektfähig: "Diese Vorgehensweise zahlt auf den Projektfortschritt ein." Wer mit klassischem deutschem Sprachgefühl aufgewachsen ist, dem sträuben sich hier die Nackenhaare. Aber wie beim Sprachwandel üblich zahlt irgendwann natürlich die Gewohnheit auf die Minderung dieses Gefühls ein. (Brrr! Schüttel!)

---

<sup>1</sup> So wörtlich gehört bei einem Manager-Vortrag heute bei uns im Großbetrieb.

<sup>2</sup> Wortwörtlich Birgit Dietze, Vertreterin der IG-Metall aus dem Bezirk Berlin-Brandenburg in der Sendung "Zur Diskussion" des Deutschlandfunk am 3.3.2021, ca. 19:20 Uhr.

Comment: Ich habe das noch nicht gehört und hätte es für eine missglückte Übersetzung von *contributes to* gehalten.

Comment: @guidot   Wie gesagt, es scheint Manager- und Betriebswirte-Jargon zu sein. Ich hätte vermutet, dass es (natürlich, woher sonst) aus dem Amerikanischen kommt, irgendwas wie "xy pays in on z", jedoch finde ich keine konkreten Nachweise einer solchen Phrase im Englischen.

Comment: Du Ärmster! In welch abgründiger Gesellschaft musst du dich bewegen!? Selbst die Sprache ist da schon so verbogen, dass es nur noch um den schnöden Mammon geht. :(

Answer (score 3):

Hinter der Metapher vom "einzahlen (auf ein Konto)" steckt die Idee, dass man dadurch ein Guthaben hat und Zinsen bekommt. Mitarbeiter, die "auf ein Projekt einzahlen" sollen durch diese Vorstellung dazu motiviert werden, eine Anstrengung auf sich zu nehmen und Entbehrungen zu ertragen, weil sie dadurch "Miteigentümer" des Erfolgs werden und die Effekte ihrer Bemühungen "ausgezahlt" bekommen. Ob dieser Ertrag materiell (Lohnerhöhung, Arbeitsplatzsicherheit) oder nur ideel ist (Stolz, Identifikation mit der Firma), hängt vom Kontext ab.

Die Metapher vom Einzahlen ist nicht nur im betrieblichen Management gebräuchlich, sondern wird in vielen Zusammenhängen gebraucht, in denen jemand in Vorleistung geht, um erst später eine Gegenleistung oder einen Etrag zu erhalten, z.B. "[das Beziehungskonto aufladen](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=beziehungskonto)". Die Metapher des Beziehungskontos geht möglicherweise auf John Gottman und Howard Markman zurück, die die Grundlagen ehelicher Zufriedenheit untersucht und es in diesem Zusammenhang verwendet haben.

Dass berufliche und private Beziehungen Tauschgeschäfte zugrundeliegen ist eine in der sozial- und wirtschaftspsychologie weit verbreitete Grundannahme und verschiedene Psychologen haben unterschiedliche [Austauschtheorien](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austauschtheorie) entwickelt, um deren Regeln zu beschreiben. In diesen Theorien spielen die Vorstellungen von Investition und Ertrag eine zentrale Rolle. Diese werden in den unterschiedlichen Theorien unterschiedlich benannt – *input*/*outcome*, Geben und Nehmen usw. –, immer liegt ihnen jedoch dasselbe wirtschaftliche Prinzip zugrunde.

Gottmann und Kollegen benutzen beispielsweise die Metapher eines Bankkontos:

> Another economy metaphor offered in the context of behavior exchange theory is the “bank account” model of marriage (Gottman et al. 1976). In this metaphor, positive exchanges are described as investments or “deposits” that maintain a favorable emotional balance and ensure stability and satisfaction of the relationship, while negative exchanges are considered “withdrawals” from that account that disrupt a favorable balance. (aus: [Encyclopedia of Couple and Family Therapy](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F978-3-319-49425-8_103))

Gottmans Modell ist in der Psychologie weit verbreitet und allgemein bekannt. Sucht man auf Google Scholar beispielsweise nach wissenschaftlichen Publikationen, [die sich mit Mitarbeiterzufriedenheit beschäftigen und Gottman zitieren](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=de&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22employee%20satisfaction%22%20%22Gottman%22%20%22marriage%22&btnG=), findet man immerhin 86 Veröffentlichungen. Es ist davon auszugehen, dass auf dem Weg über Theorien zur Mitarbeiterführung auch seine Metapher Einzug in Managementseminare gefunden hat. So verwendt Chip Conley in seinem Buch *Peak*, in dem es darum geht, wie Firmen (bzw. deren Führungskräfte) ihre Beziehungen zu Mitarbeitern, Kunden und Investoren gestalten können, um deren Vertrauen und letztlich deren Investitionen (in Form von Geld, Einkäufen oder beruflichem Engagement) zu gewinnen, unter anderem von "Abhebungen vom emotionalen Bankkonto" *(withdrawals from the emotional bank account)* oder einem "Guthaben von Vertrauen auf dem Bankkonto" *(reservoir of goodwill in the bank account)*.

Ökonomische Metaphern sind in der Psychologie weit verbreitet. Die Psychologen haben von den Ökonomen die Vorstellung übernommen, dass Menschen nach wirtschaftlichen Gesichtspunkten handeln. Es gibt einen regen Austausch und viele Überlappungen zwischen Wirtschaftswissenschaften und Psychologie, und so gibt es auch eine starke Diffundierung von Modellen des einen Bereichs in den anderen. Und wie Freud versucht hat das Funktionieren der Psyche mit der Metapher der seinerzeit fortschrittlichen Dampfmaschine zu erfassen (Triebe erzeugen Druck) und spätere Psychologen das Gedächtnis mit einem Computer verglichen (Kurzzeitgedächtnis = Arbeitsspeicher, Langzeitgedächtnis = Festplatte), so bedienen sich andere Psychologen eines anderen vertrauten Vorstellungsbereiches (dem Bankkonto), um andernfalls hoch abstrakte und schwer verständliche Vorgänge anschaulich zu machen.

Comment: Vielen Dank für diese interessanen Begleitgedanken zur kapitalistischen Fundierung (oder Infiziertheit?) unseres Denkens. Da ist sicherlich was dran. Allerdings ging es mir - viel simpler - hier zunächst um die formale Herkunft dieses ja auch syntaktisch etwas auffälligen Ausdrucks "einzahlen auf". Ich kenne das sonst nur als "(Geld) einzahlen auf's Sparkonto". Nun wäre dies ja geradezu eine Bestätigung Deiner These - aber nur, wenn es ein originär deutscher Ausdruck ist und nicht etwa eine Übertragung aus dem Allesdominenglischen.

Comment: Zur Ergänzung, die du später vorgenommen hast (Verweis auf Gottmann et al.): Ah! Spannender Aspekt! Du schlägst hier also als Erklärung vor, dass die Phrase aus der Wirtschaftspsychologie in den Betriebs-Sprech übergegangen ist.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Menschen, die in Führungspositionen arbeiten, haben oft Wirtschaft studiert, und dabei lernt man zwangsläufig diese Therorien kennen. Andere, die nicht Wirtschaft studiert haben, lesen Bücher oder besuchen Schulungen, in denen dieselben Theorien vermittelt werden. Wenn man sich mit Mitarbeiterführung beschäftigt, sind solche Ideen omnipräsent. Wie verbreitet das ist, dass manche Führungskräfte diese Metaphern dann, wie von dir berichtet, in den innerbetrieblichen Sprachgebrauch einbringen,weiß ich nicht.

Answer (score 3):

Ich kenne diese Phrase auch. Der Ursprung ist ganz klar "auf ein Konto einzahlen", denn die Bedeutung ist die gleiche, wie wenn man sagt:

> Von unser Umstellung auf die xyz-Methodik werden wir auch später beim Bla-Bla-Blupp-Projekt profitieren.

Im Büro-Deutsch braucht man halt immer wieder diese neuen Phrasen, die dann eine Weile "fresh" klingen, bis sie allmählich auf die Bullshit-Bingo-Karten wandern, und wenig später kann sie keiner mehr hören. Und genau für diese "Freshness" ist es eher hilfreich, wenn die Phrase auf zunächst ungewöhnlich klingende Weise benutzt wird. Das macht sie nur attraktiver für diejenigen, die sich damit distinguieren möchten.

Das Abstrahieren von der ursprünglichen Bedeutung passiert dabei stufenweise, aber diese Entwicklung sieht man der Phrase am Schluss nicht mehr an. Am Anfang mag man noch sowas gesagt haben wie:

> Mit unser Umstellung auf ... zahlen wir auch auf unsere Agilität ein, die wir beim ...-Projekt brauchen werden.

Und das wird dann im Lauf der Zeit weiter verkürzt, um prägnanter zu klingen.

Einen entsprechenden englischen Ausdruck, auf den das zurückgehen könnte, sehe ich in diesem Fall auch nicht.

Dieser und semantisch ähnliche Ausdrücke wie "wir investieren damit in ..." oder "wir bereiten uns damit auch vor auf..." betreffen sehr alltägliche Überlegungen, deshalb ist es wenig verwunderlich, dass sich da auch immer wieder neue Ausdrucksweisen etablieren.

Comment: Interessant. Eine moderne Betriebswirte- und Bürohengste-Phrase, die einmal nicht aus dem Amerikenglischen kommt... wenn sich das bewahrheitet, wäre es fast eine kleine linguistische Sensation!